# Как узнать координаты окна Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть код, который выводит размер и координаты вообще всех окон. Но мне надо узнать координаты окон с нужным мне названием. Как это сделать?

```
import win32gui

def callback(hwnd, extra):
    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    x = rect[0]
    y = rect[1]
    w = rect[2] - x
    h = rect[3] - y
    print ("Window %s:" % win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
    print ("\tLocation: (%d, %d)" % (x, y))
    print ("\t    Size: (%d, %d)" % (w, h))

def main():
    win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, что такое `окно c нужным мне названием`. Вы можете показать изображение с окном, которое имеет нужное вам название?

Comment: Добавил изображение

Comment: я так понимаю, что вас интересует окно `ACC` - так? Покажите как вы видите строку вывода `print ("Window %s:" % win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))` , которая содержит информацию об `ACC`, а также запустите диспетчер задач и посмотрите, что вы там видите  на вкладке `Приложения`.

Comment: Да меня интересует окно ACC. Строку вывода и что я вижу на вкладке Приложеня(я так понял что вы имели в виду вкладку процессы) я показал на скриншоте по ссылке: https://prnt.sc/102ylgg

Comment: и что вам мешает в самом начале функции `callback` поставить условие 
`if win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) == "ACC":`, а все остальное сдвинуть на 
четыре позиции вправо?

Comment: Спасибо, выручили. Я бы сам не додумался, еще только начинаю python изучать

Answer (score 1):

Можно получить размеры окна через библиотеку ahk, естественно её нужно установить (`pip install ahk`)

```
from ahk import AHK
ahk = AHK()

a = ahk.find_window(title=b'ACC')
print(a.rect)
```

Comment: Нужно тоже иметь установленную самую программу **AutoHotkey**, потому что пакет **ahk** является только интерфейсом к нее для работы в Питоне. +1.